# How to open the next page on click mouse

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

### TLDR

> I want to implement `nested routing` in React. What library can I use?

### Question

Good day, everyone! I have headers. For each title, I have a description. For example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the below example. I want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link

### Example

https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y

Comment: you could use router if you want to pass the active index into the url and then use that to change the current display. Or just use redux or rxjs or context API. I would suggest taking a look at the context API as it seems you're just starting out .
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, can I use redux instead of context?

Comment: yes you can use Redux. Go with what you feel comfortable using. since it's just a simple content replacement, Redux should be fine.

Comment: You can use simple ```useState``` if you only want to change just the description of the headings clicked.

Comment: Ketan Ramteke - Thanks for the answer.  Yes, useState or setState is fine to change the text, but I would like to know what to use for the titles, because when you click on the title, the text should change, can you use a regular NavLink Router or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example using simple `useState` hook.

[image]

Full Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Heading1",
    description:
      "Heading 1 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Heading2",
    description:
      "Heading 2 Good day, everyone! I have headers. For each title, I have a description. For example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y I want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Heading3",
    description:
      "Heading 3 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Heading4",
    description:
      "Heading 4 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Heading5",
    description:
      "Heading 5 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "Heading6",
    description:
      "Heading 6 Good day, everyone! \nI have headers. For each title, I have a description. \nFor example, I want the text to change, when I click on heading 2, please pay attention to the example, https://ibb.co/8mCHK5y \nI want to know what is best to use for such purposes? react-router or something else? for example some npm package. And what if there are such examples or lessons on the Internet, please leave me a link"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="headings">
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIndex(i);
            }}
          >
            {d.title}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="description">
        <div className="content">{data[index]["description"]}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hypatia-t5beo?file=/src/App.js:0-3485)

PS: I was busy coding this thing and didn't saw your latest comment, jeez.
But posting it anyway, I hope it helps somebody.